# Better Approach use Task vs work order?

Tags: case, tasks, casemilestone

I have requirement to create task for an case but each task should be track for SLA violation. It is not possible in term of Task, Task doesn't support for the  milestone. After reading lot of article i have got solution instead of using task we can use work order. So that i can add milestone to work order. I did test also , yes we can add milestone to an work order.

- My question  is that what make different between task and work order?
- What is work order all about & when to use it properly ?
- If work order can act as Task object, What is the purpose of the task object existing in salesforce?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My question is that what make different between task and work order?

A Task is a simple one-shot activity. You use it to track a single phone call with a customer, an email that was sent or received, or to do something simple like sending out a contract.

A Work Order is used to track work done for a customer, which typically may involve several steps, such as diagnosing the issue, ordering parts, performing the service repair, and any cleanup tasks afterwards.

> What is work order all about & when to use it properly ?

Work Orders are used to track service and repairs. It is part of the larger Service Cloud feature. You use it when a client needs some service. You should not use it for simple tasks, such as a phone call or an email.

> If work order can act as Task object, What is the purpose of the task object existing in salesforce?

It can't. A Work Order, while conceptually similar, represents a different type of activity that is usually much larger in scope and may last several days or even weeks. A task, by contrast, usually lasts for a few minutes to a few hours, and typically is not specifically related to a service call or repair.